# Volume form in a tube

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface. Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ a local ortonormal frame o $S$ and $\varphi : U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$ a coordinate chart such that $d\varphi((1,0)) = e_1, d\varphi(0,1) = e_2$. Consider
$$
F(x,y,t) = \varphi(x,y) + tN_p,
$$
where $N_p$ is local unitary normal vector field of $S$. For small values of $t$ its clear that $F$ is an inmersion of $U \times I \to \mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, the image of $F$ is a tube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to compute the volume form $F_*(dx \wedge dy \wedge dt)$ of the tube.

The next was my attemp.
$$
\partial_x F =  \partial_x \varphi + t\partial_x N = e_1 + t\partial_xN
$$
$$
\partial_y F = \partial_y\varphi + t\partial_y N = e_2 + t\partial_y N
$$
$$
\partial_t F = N
$$
and
$$
dF_{(x,y,t)}(v,\lambda) = d\varphi_p(v) + tdN_p(v) + \lambda N_p.
$$

We can rewrite the term $dN_p$ considering $\{e_1,e_2,e_3 := N\}$ which is a local frame
$$
\partial_xN = \Gamma_{11} e_1 + \Gamma_{12} e_2 + L_{13} e_3
$$
$$
\partial_yN = \Gamma_{21} e_1 + \Gamma_{22} e_2 + L_{23} e_3
$$
Then
$$
\partial_x F = e_1 + t\left( \Gamma_{11} e_1 + \Gamma_{12} e_2 + L_{13} e_3\right)
$$
$$
\partial_y F = e_2 + t\left( \Gamma_{21} e_1 + \Gamma_{22} e_2 + L_{23} e_3\right)
$$
$$
\partial_t F = N
$$

So how can I continue? I know that the volume form must be something like

$$
\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1 + t\Gamma_{11} & 0 & tL_{13} \\
0 & 1 + t\Gamma_{22} & t L_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right) dvol_S \wedge dt
$$

but this result it is not coherent with $\langle \partial_{x_i}F,\partial_{x_j}F\rangle$. The result its obtain doing $\langle \partial_{x_i}F,e_j\rangle$, but I can't see why this is true.

Comment: Do you know differential forms and how to calculate geometry of moving frames using them? The way you're doing this is just very awkward. I would suggest working (locally) in a principal moving frame (principal directions for $e_1$, $e_2$) to make things more transparent.